# $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,n]} e^{-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}d\lambda_{1}(x) $

Tags: limits, lebesgue-integral

Given the following problem: Calculate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,n]} e^{-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}d\lambda_{1}(x)$$

My try was to find a function $g\geq |f_n|$ so I can use the dominated convergence theorem (by removing the integral bounds by instead multiplicating the function by $\chi_{[0,n]}$ inside the integral) but I cant find one. Is it the wrong idea or which convergence theorem do I need here? Thanks

Comment: You know the exponential term is positive and bounded above by $e^{-x}$.

Comment: What does $d\lambda_1(x)$ mean?

Comment: @BenjaminWang it means we're integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the sequence of functions $\left\{x\mapsto e^{-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ satisfies the assumptions of the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and notice also that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)=e^{-x}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]}e^{-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}}~\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x}~\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x \leqslant \sqrt{x^2 + 1/n^2}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has $$\exp(-\,{x}) \geqslant \exp\left(-\,\sqrt{x^2 + 1/n^2}\right),$$
so that Lebesgue's DCT holds.